# IntelliJ only builds tests if I run "./gradlew tests" from the command line

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I was having an issue when trying to run new tests on IntelliJ, where it was giving me an error that said the tests didn't exist:

```
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:189)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
...
```

So then I tried running older tests, and those worked. And so, just for testing purposes, I changed some of those tests to be just something like this:

```
@Test
    fun `the test`() {
        assertTrue(false)
    }
```

But when I ran the tests through IntelliJ, they all still passed every time.

After searching a lot, I saw someone online saying to try doing "./gradlew tests", and that worked exactly as expected! After that I tried running the tests through IntelliJ again, and this time it also worked as expected! However, now when I change anything, IntelliJ still gives me the same results as the last time I ran the gradlew command, and the only way to fix it is to do "./gradlew tests" *every time* I change the tests or add new ones.

So I guess my question is, how do I fix this and get IntelliJ to build the tests before it runs them?

---

EDIT: This is my "build.gradle.kts" file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
}

group = "pt.isel.pc"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val ktlint: Configuration by configurations.creating

dependencies {

    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.0-alpha7")

    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))

    ktlint("com.pinterest:ktlint:0.48.2") {
        attributes {
            attribute(Bundling.BUNDLING_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Bundling.EXTERNAL))
        }
    }
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
}

val outputDir = "${project.buildDir}/reports/ktlint/"
val inputFiles = project.fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "src", "include" to "**/*.kt"))
val ktlintCheck by tasks.creating(JavaExec::class) {
    inputs.files(inputFiles)
    outputs.dir(outputDir)

    description = "Check Kotlin code style."
    classpath = ktlint
    mainClass.set("com.pinterest.ktlint.Main")
    args = listOf("src/**/*.kt")
}

tasks.named("check") {
    dependsOn("ktlintCheck")
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling test classes before test? I am not sure, but seems that somehow in IDEA the dependency between `test` and `testClasses` is broken! Can you share your build.gradle?

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Edited post to include the build.gradle file. I'm not sure how to check if it's compiling the test classes before the test.

Comment: @WillPotato will the behaviour change if you choose IntelliJ runner instead of Gradle in "Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Run tests using"?